# Blender three.js exporter ignores world map?

Tags: three.js, blender

I'm trying to export mirrored jewelry models from Blender into some WebGL package using cube mapped environmental maps to afford dynamic reflections.

After struggling with Babylon.js and Blend4Web exporters for Blender, the later which turns out simply doesn't support simple dynamic reflection mapping, I was delighted to find the Three.js exporter included in the World panel its own environmental texture mapping pop-up menu with CubicReflectionMapping (along with spherical too) and I got it to reflect nicely off a simple model.

Though any texture I apply to the model exports fine as a Three JSON file, and even gets its assigned image conveniently copied over to the export directory, the world map is just ignored no matter what I check in the export options. The editor/viewer at http://threejs.org/editor/ allows me to view the JSON scene and then manually add my environmental map just fine. It also alerts me that my model map needs to be manually loaded too but puts up no warning about the environmental map since that's not included in the JSON file at all.

Am I supposed to bake the World onto the model or something? I have no idea for lack of a manual or any sample files. To make the map appear within Blender I must check Horizon in the Influence panel of the texture.

I'm using Blender 2.73 with the Three.js exporter 71.

Comment: env maps do not get attached to the JSON. You must apply them manually after wards as per example linked below.

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature on the exporter that handles data attached to the `World` object. Have you looked at how this scene is setup?
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap

Is it close to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The issue is how to export that cubemap data from Blender